# The plural of letters

Tags: plural-forms, nouns

I realise the first concatenation of the `'s` and it's example.
Second one which says `double p or double l`.So I couldn't understand that.Please help me to describe that with some example.

**1,** The plural of letters of the alphabet is formed by adding `'s`.

```
t - t's 
d - d's
p - p's
l - l's
```

**2,** but the plural of `'p' (page); 'l' (line), 'n' (noun), 'v' (Verb) and Ms (Manuscript)` is formed by doubling these letters:

```
p - pp(pages)
l - ll(lines)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With 'pp.' and 'll.' you are not forming the plural of the characters (letters) but the plural **abbreviation**: the plural of the word which the abbreviation represents.

So these have the following pronunciations and meanings:

```
A's or a's      AYZ               meaning two or more of the character 'A'
B's or b's      BEEZ              meaning two or more of the character 'B'
L's or l's      ELLZ              meaning two or more of the character 'L'
P's or p's      PEEZ              meaning two or more of the character 'P'
V's or v's      VEEZ              meaning two or more of the character 'V'
```

But these have quite different pronunciations and meanings:

```
ll.             LINES             meaning two or more lines
pp.             PAGES             meaning two or more pages
Mss.            MANUSCRIPTS       meaning two or more manuscripts
vv.             VOLUMES  or       meaning two or more volumes
                VERSES   or       meaning two or more verses
                VERSIONS          meaning two or more versions
```

Note that when **V** stands for 'verb' it is neither a character nor an abbreviation but a symbol employed in linguistic notation.

Comment: Thanks for reply.So what you are conveying is 'l' to be prnounced with stress like 'll' If it is Lines.Am I right?

Comment: @sunleo No - if it is the abbreviation, you simply say 'lines', with whatever stress the context calls for. "ll. 13-15" is spoken "lines thirteen to fifteen". But "Two l's" is spoken "Two ells".